# CAN 2.0 BUS protocol

Tags: ascii, can-bus

Can any body help me to know how the identifiers are assigned in CAN bus protocol? what does these identifiers tell? For example what is the meaning of this ASCII identifier '152407439'?
Actually, I have CAN data and there are continuous identifiers but I am unable to decode them. Can someone please help me to decode them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The meaning of CAN identifiers are defined by the underlying protocol. They can mean anything. The only thing you can be sure is that the lower IDs have higher priority on the bus. What's the name of the protocol you use? Maybe CANopen, DeviceNet or J1939?

Comment: Thanks Tagli for your reply.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  How do I know about it? As I am very new to this. Moreover, can you please tell me that who generate these identifiers? CAN converter or processor of the system?

Comment: You need to refer to device manual. I have experience only with CANopen. In CANopen, the IDs are assigned during bus configuration, but they must satisfy some constraints. Other protocols may be different, I don't know anything about them. Again, you need device manual unless you have deep knowledge about CAN protocols and willing to reverse engineer them.